# Install cx_Oracle for python 3.4 in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.4, cx-oracle

Please help me installing cx_Oracle for python 3.4.

I am able to install it for python 2.7 using the below method.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DwbOozQrZ8

however it is not working for 3.4. Please help me.

Comment: Please show the commands you are executing and the errors you are receiving.

Comment: I dont have any idea how to install cx_Oracle for python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the instant client installed on your machine and you are able to connect to your database with SQL*Plus. Also make sure you have the instant client development package installed on your machine.

Second, run the command

pip install cx_Oracle

This will download the source package and build. If you are using the instant client nothing else needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

My Django 1.8.4 works perfectly with cx_Oracle Python 2.7 set on Linux, but it's not even mentioned that latest cx_Oracle supports Python 3.4 for Linux (for Win it does). As result attempt `pip install cx_Oracle` gets

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files
```